# Cheap / Easy source of small amount of ferromagnetic metal

Tags: magnets

Hello all I have a magnet in my car to stick my phone to the dashboard. But I changed phone and now my new phone needs some metal stuck to the case in order to attract to the magnet.

I read online these metals are called ferromagnetic (iron, steel, and others).

I wonder if any of you fine folks can suggest me a place I can butcher some from something I might already have at home (or can be easily found). At the moment we have the lockdown and most shops are shut. I can't figure it out on my own haha.

Just need like an inch or 2 square piece of metal that will  stick to my magnet in the car. Sadly, I don't have great tools, but might be able to borrow some rudimental hand tools.

Thanks for reading and any help!

Comment: Welcome to Engineering! This looks like a [resource-hunting question](http://meta.engineering.stackexchange.com/q/10/1832). Such questions are prone to becoming out-dated or being excessively localized, and are therefore considered off-topic for this site.

Comment: @Wasabi asking for magnetic material ideas is not likely to become dated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A steel washer would work well.

Find one about 1" in diameter and that should be sufficient.

If you have a file or sanding tool then round the edges off.

Make sure the surfaces you are gluing are "keyed" ie scratched to provide a better joint.

Comment: Thank you mate! I would upvote but the site wont allow me to :D

Comment: Good answer, but make sure it is regular steel and not stainless steel.

Comment: @EricShain you can test it on the magnet that is in the car... And I did say steel, not stainless.

Comment: I'm not criticizing your answer (in fact, I'm the upvote), just that some people don't know that stainless steel isn't usually attracted to a magnet. Some lay people think of stainless as better steel. If the magnet is mounted in the car, then that would imply having to purchase the washer first. I'm just trying to help avoid wasted effort on the OP's part.

Comment: @EricShain even if you gave some a washer of both types they wouldn't know the difference... and thanks anyway.

Comment: At least around here, stainless washers are more expensive than plain steel.